# Pointers - unexpected output

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, implicit-conversion

I am going through a book and this example isn't explained properly.

As far as I understand, the array variable (`nums`) is a pointer to an array. Next step I declare a variable `choice` and give it a value of the address of the array. Then I pass the value behind choice(which I thought would be {1, 2, 3}) to the last element of the array. Printing the last element I get 1. How come that? What don't I understand about pointers?

```
int nums[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *choice = nums;
nums[2] = *choice;
printf("%i", nums[2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nums` is *not* a pointer to an array.  `nums` *is* an array, and when used in an expression it is converted to a pointer to the first element.

So when you do this:

```
int *choice = nums;
```

It makes `choice` point to the first element of `nums`.  Then when you use `*choice` you get the value of the first element of `nums`.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand, the array variable (nums) is a pointer to an
> array

No, you are wrong. Arrays and pointers are two different kinds of objects.

But arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In this declaration

```
int nums[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

there is declared an array with three elements.

In this declaration

```
int *choice = nums;
```

there is declared a pointer that is initialized by the array designator `nums` that used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first (initial) element.

The above declaration in fact is equivalent to the following declaration

```
int *choice = &nums[0];
```

Dereferencing the pointer we will get the first element (lvalue) of the array.

Hence this statement

```
nums[2] = *choice;
```

is equivalent to

```
nums[2] = nums[0];
```

As `nums[0]` (`*nums`) is equal to 1 then this call of `printf`

```
printf("%i", nums[2]);
```

will output the value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because choice and nums are pointers to **the first element of the array**

```
nums[2] = *choice;
```

is the same as

```
nums[2] = *(&choice[0]);
```

and therefore the same as

```
nums[2] = choice[0];
```

And, because you did

```
int *choice = nums;
```

it is the same as

```
nums[2] = nums[0];
```

So, at the end the values of nums are:

1 2 1

So, nums[2] is 1